# Why is sed regex substitution not working?

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I need to do something very simple with `sed`: I need to get the commit hash out of this string `HEAD detached at 19d7ea9`.

Here's my attempt at it using `sed`

```
echo "HEAD detached at 19d7ea9" | sed 's/HEAD\ detached\ at\ \(.\+\)/\1/'
```

However, that command just doesn't work, and I can't quite figure out why. I know I can do it different like `sed 's/HEAD\ detached\ at//` and have the same result. But I can't seem to figure out why the first method doesn't work.

Any answer will be appreciated. And this is my first time using `sed` (I know I'm late to the party), so please overlook at noobie mistake.

---

EDIT: Thanks for all the answers. It seems like using the `-E` flag is the most straightforward way to solve this.

I tried to follow @ooga's answer with another example, but that also failed miserably. Again, I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here:

EXAMPLE 2:
I am trying to see whether the repo is ahead or behind remote, and by how many commits. Here's my code

```
status="On branch master Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit. (use "git push" to publish your local commits) Changes not staged for commit: (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed) (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to..."

echo $status | sed -E 's/Your branch is (ahead|behind).+([0-9]+) comm)/\2 \1/'
```

Any further help on this topic is appreciated. I wonder why I can't get this whole `sed` business right.

Comment: Try this: `sed 's/HEAD detached at \(.*\)/\1/'`

Comment: Why are you escaping spaces?

Comment: Do you know what is the version of sed you use?

Comment: Your `sed` command works fine for me, even with the superfluously escaped spaces.  If `sed` continues to fail for you, you could also try `awk`: `echo "HEAD detached at 19d7ea9" | awk '{print $4}'`

Comment: Just fyi `\+` doesn't work on `sed` on OSX hence I suggested `sed 's/HEAD detached at \(.*\)/\1/'` above.

Comment: @anubhava: The value of saying ***why***, not just what. :-)

Comment: Sorry didn't get your comment. I have already answered why it might not work if OP is using BSD `sed` e.g. on OSX.

Comment: @anubhava The equivalent expression to match at least one would be `\(..*\)`.

Comment: Yes I know that `.*` is not same as `.+` but it will do the job here.

Answer (score 3):

Use "extended" (modern) regular expression syntax with the `-E` flag (on OSX,  or the `-r` flag on GNU). That way not only do you have the `+` quantifier, but you don't need to use backslashes in front of it or the parentheses.

```
sed -E 's/HEAD detached at (.+)/\1/'
```

Comment: In fact, with extended ERE's, it is not so much "don't need to use" as "must not use" backslashes before the parentheses, since escapaing the parentheses would mean look for literal parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

You got your answer about sed versions but FWIW in awk you just tell it to print the last space-separated field on the line:

```
awk '{print $NF}' file
```

Comment: Wow! That is really neat and elegant!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `+` is not a valid quantifier in POSIX [Basic Regular Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html#tag_09_03), but `*` is, so the following works and should be portable even to OS X.

```
echo "HEAD detached at 19d7ea9" | sed  's/HEAD detached at \(.*\)/\1/'
```